# What does "v" mean in mongo index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

In mongodb, we can use `db.collection.getIndexes()` to get all indexes, output is something like:

```
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "counters"
    }
]
```

Most properties are pretty self-explanatory except for "v", can't seem to find any documentation about this.
Does any one know what "v" means here? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`v` is the version.

[Version 0](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2-compatibility/#version-0-indexes) has been disallowed since MongoDB 3.2,

I have heard that only version 2+ can be used with MongoDB 4.2, but I am unable to find a documentation link to confirm that.

See also:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/#versions
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#versions

Comment: I really love the devs who did it. I just cannot understand why it is so difficult to name the field "version" instead of just "v", so unintuitive